# Add error bars to chart with Color encoding

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to add error bars to a chart with mark.errorbar() but when I add a color encoding, the bars disappear.

This is the code for the base chart:

```
base = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_line().encode(
x = alt.X('Session:N'),
y = alt.Y('CR Lever'),
color = alt.Color('Phenotype:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['GT','IN','ST'],
                                                 range = ['red', 'blue', 'green']))
```

[image]

But when I try to get a chart for error bars with the following code, nothing appears.

```
alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_errorbar(extent='stderr').encode(
x = alt.X('Session:N'),
y = alt.Y('CR Lever'),
color = alt.Color('Phenotype:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['GT','IN','ST'],
                                                 range = ['red', 'blue', 'green']))
```

[image]

Just dropping the color encoding allows the error bars to show up, but is there any way to get them on the color-split chart?

Full min reproduceable example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import altair as alt

# Construct DF
base_df = pd.DataFrame()
id = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
c = ['ST', 'IN', 'GT']
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = []

base_df['id'] = np.repeat(id, 5)
base_df['c'] = np.repeat(c, 25)
base_df['x'] = np.tile(x, 15)

for group in base_df['c']:
  if group == 'ST':
    y.append(random.randint(90,130))
  if group == 'IN':
    y.append(random.randint(30,80))
  if group == 'GT':
    y.append(random.randint(1, 10))

base_df['y'] = y

chart_df = base_df[['c','x','y']].groupby(['x','c']).agg('mean').reset_index()

#Create the base chart to which I want to add error bars
base = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_line().encode(
  x = alt.X('x:N'),
  y = alt.Y('y'),
  color = alt.Color('c:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['GT','IN','ST'],
                                                  range = ['red', 'blue', 'green']))
)


#Error bar chart without grouping with color encoding. This works fine
bars_no_group = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_errorbar(extent='stderr').encode(
  x = alt.X('x:N'),
  y = alt.Y('y')
)

#Error bar chart with grouping with color encoding. This does not work
bars_group = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_errorbar(extent='stderr').encode(
  x = alt.X('x:N'),
  y = alt.Y('y'),
  color = alt.Color('c:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['GT','IN','ST'],
                                                  range = ['red', 'blue', 'green']))
)
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which includes sample data, so that it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: Updated with minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because there are not enough data points to create an error bar in each color group. If you aggregate the data via altair instead of doing the groupby in pandas, it works as expected since there now are multiple data points for each color and x position:

```
# Comment out this groupby operation to make sure there are enough data points in each color group
chart_df = base_df[['c','x','y']] #.groupby(['x','c']).agg('mean').reset_index()

#Create the base chart to which I want to add error bars
lines = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_line().encode(
  x = alt.X('x:N'),
  y = alt.Y('mean(y)'),
  color = alt.Color('c:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['GT','IN','ST'],
                                                  range = ['red', 'blue', 'green']))
)

errorbars = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_errorbar(extent='stderr').encode(
  x = alt.X('x:N'),
  y = alt.Y('y'),
  color = alt.Color(
      'c:N',
      scale=alt.Scale(
          domain=['GT','IN','ST'],
          range = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
      )
  )
)

lines + errorbars
```

[image]